# CoreAnimation taking lot of memory

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, core-animation

I am experiencing a problem where coreAnimation taking lot of memory. Each time I repaint all cells of a UItableview, It keep increasing as I see in xcode Profiler.

I removed the drawRect method of my custom UITableviewCell and tried again but same problem appears.

If I remove code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it solves the problem. So i think it is somewhere in there. But i still cannot figure it out.

I am not using any animation and I am not drawing anything using Core Graphics. Any thoughts?

```
UITableViewCellForRow *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contentRowsIdForCaching];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCellForRow alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:contentRowsIdForCaching];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    NSArray *arrValues = [self getRow:indexPath.row];
    cell.arrValues = arrValues;

    arrValues = nil;
}
else
{          
   [self getRowIntoArray:indexPath.row array:[cell getMutableValues]];

   [cell setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

EDIT: I change reuseidentifier to tell UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexpath to recreate all cells and then call reloaddata method. Do I need to release or dealloc those older cells?

Comment: Sounds like you're not re-using `UITableViewCell`s properly

Comment: I am using Uitableviewcell's drawrect method to draw Grid like structure. I have to re-paint all cells as column width change. In that case I have to recreate cells but I am re-using cells that's for sure.

Comment: How are you sure? Let's see your code

Comment: Wait... Are you using a different reuse id for each row? What is contentRowsIDForCaching?

Comment: I am not using different values of contentRowsIDForCaching for each row. Each time I need to change layout of subviews in cell, i force cells to recreate their layout. To do that, I update contentRowsIDForCaching which is timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read an Apple Documentation about UITableview performance that one should create layout of subviews inside table cell only once and resize, reposition, hide/show them when needed.